# What is clang's equivalent to -rdynamic gcc flag?

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I can't find any similar option that would include all the function names into the final release binary. Or does `clang` do it by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least clang 3.3 seems to support `-rdynamic` though neither `clang --help` nor the manpage documents it. (If you are on OSX, -rdynamic isn't needed)

gcc `-rdynamic` says "-rdynamic
           Pass the flag --export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it."

So clang should also be able to do the same with `-Wl,--export-dynamic`.

Comment: My bad, should have added that I specifically mean OS X. Why is it not needed?

Comment: It's the default to put all symbols in the global symbol table on OSX

Comment: Clang 5 does not support `-export-dynamic` but does support `-rdynamic`.

Answer (score 22):

The correct answer to this question is `-Wl,-export_dynamic` and **not** `-Wl,--export-dynamic`.

`-Wl,--export-dynamic` is only correct if you are using the GNU linker on ELF platforms.

This question is about OS X.

**Source:** http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-236.3/src/ld/Options.cpp

```
...
else if ( strcmp(arg, "-export_dynamic") == 0 ) {
    fExportDynamic = true;
}
...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (Tested with AppleClang on Catalina)

Answer (score 1):

My Google-fu is telling me you can replace that by

```
-Wl,--export-dynamic
```

Which is what GCC usually passes to the linker when it is passed `-rdynamic`. I would first try it without anything, and see if the flag was necessary.